# Process 'command usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, gradle

I run an application on Android Studio but I have an error like : Execution failed for task org.gradle.process.internal ExecException Process command /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java finished with non-zero exit value 2

My software and hardware informations

**Operating System = Ubuntu 15.04 kde 
Development Tool = Android Studio 1.3.2 
CPU = intel i7 3610QM
Java = 8 (it doesnt matter I also tried 7)
**

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':TouchGalleryLibrary')
    compile project(':EditTextFormLibrary')
    compile (project(':touchImageView'))
    compile (project(':viewPagerIndicatorLibrary'))
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'
    // ExpandableTextView
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    // FlatButtonLibrary
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    // RadioButtonLibrary
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.0.1'
    // CardIOLibrary
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.2.0'
    // SmoothProgressBar
    //compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.0.1' //
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    // Google Analytics
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

**build.gradle of TouchImageView**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
        minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

**build.gradle of viewPagerIndicatorLibrary**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 4
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

I guess this problem is because of dependency conflict (support-v4:21.0.3') How can I solve this problem ?

Stack Error  Output :

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}




 Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':KitapyurduLibrary:dexDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1276)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$convertByteCode$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.doTaskAction(Dex.groovy:165)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.this$6$doTaskAction(Dex.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex$this$6$doTaskAction.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.taskAction(Dex.groovy:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
    ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read full error statement in your Gradle Console

I guess it has some kind of UNEXPECTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION,
 that is usually caused my either have multi-dex issue or duplicate dependency issue.

Try to remove half of your libraries and build the project. If this will fix the issue, you have exceeded the 65k method count.

Comment: I use multidexEnabled true but it gives me another error like : java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/InterpolatorRes.class